# SharePoint 2010 Taxonomy Issue in ie11

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, managed-metadata, taxonomy, ie-11

Data from taxonomy column is not displaying in auto search in IE11, which is working perfectly in IE8. No suggestion are displayed for IE11 taxonomy column.
Please help

Comment: could you provide some screenshots about this issue? It will be better to understand it.